# Set value of variable depending on the index of the element in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array within an array and I have a variable whose value I want to set depending on the index of the element of the array.

This is the array:

```
$data_array = array('1A' => array(3.23, 5.23, 1.23, 8.67, 2.3, 2.1, 1.27, 4.24),
                    '2A' => array(5.8, 2.23, 5.23, 2.67, 2.3, 2.1, 1.27, 4.24),
                    '3A' => array(3.23, 5.23, 1.23, 8.67, 2.3, 2.1, 1.27, 4.24),
                    '4A' => array(3.23, 5.23, 1.23, 8.67, 2.3, 2.1, 1.27, 4.24),
                    '5A' => array(3.23, 5.23, 1.23, 8.67, 2.3, 2.1, 1.27, 4.24),
                    '6A' => array(3.23, 5.23, 1.23, 8.67, 2.3, 2.1, 1.27, 4.24));
```

What I want to do is:

When it's at `index 0` of array `1A`  variable `quantity` value should be set to `1-50`

When it's at `index 1` of array `1A`, the variable value should be set to  `quantity = '51-100'`

I've coded the foreach:

```
      foreach ( $data_array as $cp => $value ) {


                            foreach ($value as $price){
                              if ($value[0]) {
                                 $quantity = '1-59';
                              }
                              else if ($value[1]){
                                 $quantity = '51-100';
                              }
                              else if ($value[2]){
                               $quantity = '101-150';
                              }
                              else if ($value[3]){
                                $quantity = '151-200';
                              }
                              else if ($value[4]){
                                $quantity = '201-250';
                              }
                              else if ($value[5]){
                                $quantity = '251-300';
                              }
                              else if ($value[6]){
                                $quantity = '301-350';
                              }
                              else if ($value[7]){
                                $quantity = '351-400';
                              }

                              //output
                              $values[] = $wpdb->prepare( "(%s, $f)", $quantity, $price );

                            }

}
```

This is returning `$quantity = '1-50'` regardless of the index of the element.

I'm not sure I'm doing it correctly. Any pointers would be appreciated.

**OUTPUT:**

```
$values[] = $wpdb->prepare( "(%s, $f)", $quantity, $price );
```

Comment: And what are the other nested arrays for? What happens if a match is found in '2A'? What is the name of the variable that has the value you want to look for? You don't seem to use it in your code...

Comment: The same if/else conditions should run.

Comment: What do you expect the out put to look lie?

Comment: The variable is `quantity` and it is not in the array. I want to set its value depending on the index of the element in the array when I run the foreach loop.

Comment: @trincot of the element which it is at, when it is running the loop.

Comment: @JasonK, I've added in the code what I have to do with the output.

Comment: So the actual values in the array (like 3.23), are not relevant at all?

Comment: @trincot, yes, it's not relevant to determine the `quantity`.

Comment: *When it's at index 0 of array* - what a variable you want to compare with values from the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the index of the `$value` array, which you can get with the `=>` syntax within the `foreach` statement. Then you can simplify the inner loop as follows:

```
foreach ($value as $i => $price){
    $quantity = ($i*50+1) . "-" . ($i*50+50);
    $values[] = $wpdb->prepare( "(%s, $f)", $quantity, $price );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this gives you what you want.

A little more data driven.

```
<?php

$data_array = array('1A' => array(3.23, 5.23, 1.23, 8.67, 2.3, 2.1, 1.27, 4.24),
                    '2A' => array(5.8, 2.23, 5.23, 2.67, 2.3, 2.1, 1.27, 4.24),
                    '3A' => array(3.23, 5.23, 1.23, 8.67, 2.3, 2.1, 1.27, 4.24),
                    '4A' => array(3.23, 5.23, 1.23, 8.67, 2.3, 2.1, 1.27, 4.24),
                    '5A' => array(3.23, 5.23, 1.23, 8.67, 2.3, 2.1, 1.27, 4.24),
                    '6A' => array(3.23, 5.23, 1.23, 8.67, 2.3, 2.1, 1.27, 4.24));

$qty = array('1-59','51-100','101-150','151-200','201-250','251-300','301-350','351-400');

foreach ( $data_array as $cp => $value ) {
    $values = array();
    for ($x=0;$x<8;$x++){
    //  echo $qty[$x] .', '. $value[$x].'<br>';
    $values[] = $wpdb->prepare( "(%s, $f)", $qty[$x], $value[$x]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're doing wrong, You're not matching any value with **if** so it's always return **true** and assign first value which is **1-50**

Note: This is suitable if your sub-array contains 8 elements, otherwise you've to add more **else if** corresponding to elements.

```
$data_array = array('1A' => array(3.23, 5.23, 1.23, 8.67, 2.3, 2.1, 1.27, 4.24),
                    '2A' => array(5.8, 2.23, 5.23, 2.67, 2.3, 2.1, 1.27, 4.24),
                    '3A' => array(3.23, 5.23, 1.23, 8.67, 2.3, 2.1, 1.27, 4.24),
                    '4A' => array(3.23, 5.23, 1.23, 8.67, 2.3, 2.1, 1.27, 4.24),
                    '5A' => array(3.23, 5.23, 1.23, 8.67, 2.3, 2.1, 1.27, 4.24),
                    '6A' => array(3.23, 5.23, 1.23, 8.67, 2.3, 2.1, 1.27, 4.24));

  foreach ( $data_array as $cp => $value ) {


                            foreach ($value as $k => $price){
                              if ($k == 0) {
                                 $quantity = '1-50';
                              }
                              else if ($k == 1){
                                 $quantity = '51-100';
                              }
                              else if ($k == 2){
                               $quantity = '101-150';
                              }
                              else if ($k == 3){
                                $quantity = '151-200';
                              }
                              else if ($k == 4){
                                $quantity = '201-250';
                              }
                              else if ($k == 5){
                                $quantity = '251-300';
                              }
                              else if ($k == 6){
                                $quantity = '301-350';
                              }
                              else if ($k == 7){
                                $quantity = '351-400';
                              }

                              //output
                             $values[] = $wpdb->prepare( "(%s, $f)", $quantity, $price );
                            }
}
```

Working example:
https://3v4l.org/hZ6kq

**Note**: Using too much **if-elseif** is not good practice, use some logic instead of if-elseif.